# Nifi 1.12 processor is not auto upgrading for custom processor

Tags: apache-nifi

I have a custom processor for AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService controller service. this has been build on top of 1.8 version .
the structure for custom processor in flow.xml.gz file is:

```
<name>AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService100</name>  <class>org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService</class>
      <bundle>
        <group>com.xxx.xx1234</group>
        <artifact>nifi-custom-ping-credentials-controller-service</artifact>
        <version>1.0.0</version>
      </bundle>
```

There are  also default AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService controller service  of 1.8version  is present which is having below configuration in flow.xml

```
<name>AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService180</name>    <class>org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService</class>
      <bundle>
        <group>org.apache.nifi</group>
        <artifact>nifi-aws-nar</artifact>
        <version>1.8.0</version>
```

So I am upgrading nifi cluster , means putting this flow.xml.gz file from 1.8 cluster to 1.12 cluster .

After the cluster up I am seeing the default AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService(1.8 version) controller is not auto upgraded to 1.12 bundle and getting invalid with error:

Error:

missing controller service validated against "any property" is invalid because controler service of this type org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService, but this is not a valid reporting task type.

log I am seeing :

2020-10-14 17:14:56,042 ERROR [main] o.a.nifi.controller.ExtensionBuilder Could not create Controller Service of type org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService for ID 25defb18-0175-1000-5bb4-febb1b1a21db due to: Unable to find bundle for coordinate org.apache.nifi:nifi-aws-nar:1.8.0; creating "Ghost" implementation
2020-10-14 17:14:56,042 INFO [main] o.a.nifi.groups.StandardProcessGroup StandardControllerServiceNode[service=GhostControllerService[id=25defb18-0175-1000-5bb4-febb1b1a21db, type=org.apache.nifi.processors.aws.credentials.provider.service.AWSCredentialsProviderControllerService], versionedComponentId=null, processGroup=StandardProcessGroup[identifier=8cb90667-0174-1000-8741-3bfe7f19db7f], active=false] added to StandardProcessGroup[identifier=8cb90667-0174-1000-8741-3bfe7f19db7f]

The is no issue in the custom processor (nifi-custom-ping-credentials-controller-service 1.0.0)   as 1.0.0 version nar file is present in the 1.12 cluster
Also no issue with other 1.8 version processor & controller service , all are auto upgraded to 1.12 version.

Could be please let me know what should be done avoid this type of issue in upgrade?